# Default Format For Decimals

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Most of the values in our system are stored as decimals - 99% of the time whole numbers are used, however occasionally numbers may be entered to 2 decimal places.

It's therefore a requirement that all numbers be displayed as whole numbers, unless a decimal is present, in which case it is to be displayed to 1 or 2 decimal places, depending on the number.

Obviously this can be achieved by using

`[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#,0.##}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`

on every field, and adding `.ToString("#,0.##")` everywhere, but this is extremely time consuming to do, especially on larger classes, not to mention making the code very difficult to read.

As this applies to all decimals - it seems like it would be much easier to just override the default format and apply this system wide.

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a default display template that will be picked up whenever you use `.DisplayFor(...)`. For a `decimal` property, you need to create the following file: `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/decimal.cshtml`

The file needs to contain a model definition, just like a regular view, and then whatever you need to render it:

```
@model decimal

@{
    <span>@Model.ToString("#,0.##")</span>
}
```

The same works for `.EditorFor(...)` with `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/decimal.cshtml`.